# How can I get the result 'TOTAL', 'USER' and the types as values in database?

Tags: obiee

I am new to OBIEE, i am trying to fetch the data as 'TOTAL', 'USER' and Other types as respective values in OBIEE.

I tried case statement in OBIEE RPD but helpless

My table looks as below,

[image: Table]

The requirement is, when client has all sess_type (ACTIVE, IDLE, DISCONNECT and RAPID) then he should be called as TOTAL, when client has sess_type in (ACTIVE, IDLE, DISCONNECT) then he should be called as USER, for remaining clients sess_type should show the corresponding values.

In OBIEE front end, if i select Client ABC then Sess_type should show as TOTAL, ACTIVE, IDLE, DISCONNECT, RAPID. If i select XYZ then sess_type should show as USER, ACTIVE, IDLE, DISCONNECT. If i select PQR then it should show only ACTIVE

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the case statement in answers and not in the RPD.

If you have problems with syntax try Bins:

I.e. Bins (criteria - edit column formula - bins) create the case statement for you.

[image]

This results in:

CASE  WHEN "SESS.TYPE" IN ('Active', 'IDLE', ...) THEN 'TOTAL'

CASE  WHEN ...

CASE  WHEN ... ELSE "SESS.TYPE" END

Comment: Hi Max, I have tried with Bins. I want the logic in RPD as new column in BMM layer.